# Laravel eloquent - use groupBy and having in the same query

Tags: mysql, laravel

Can someone change this sql query to Laravel eloquent?

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` where recipient_id = 1 group by user_id HAVING MAX(created_at)
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I think you should start with a sample data set and a desired result. Because nothing that starts with `*` and ends with `group by` ever works out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this**

*First of all you need to create model for `Message`*

```
Message::where('recipient_id',1)->groupBy('user_id')->havingRaw( 'MAX(created_at)')->get();
```